# Files being uploaded get the first letter cut off

Tags: php, html, iis

I'm migrating a website from a server with WS2003, IIS6, PHP 5.2 over to a server with WS2008, IIS7 and PHP 5.3

I have a html form that uploads files to the site.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Upload"])){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>

<form action="tester.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="Upload" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4500000" />
    <input type="file" name="artImage" id="artImage" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Works great on the old server, but on the new server, it chops off the first letter for no reason I can see. I don't know if it's an IIS setting, or a PHP setting.
Output:

```
Array
(
    [Upload] => 1
    [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 4500000
)
Array
(
    [artImage] => Array
        (
            [name] => easons_Change_(HD_Ready).jpg
            [type] => image/pjpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php99.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 498879
        )

)
```

Output from the old server, same code, same file:

```
Array
(
    [Upload] => 1
    [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 4500000
)
Array
(
    [artImage] => Array
        (
            [name] => Seasons_Change_(HD_Ready).jpg
            [type] => image/pjpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php6835.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 498879
        )

)
```

Comment: Try outputting just: `echo $_FILES['artImage']['name']`

Comment: @neal: that'd just output the same thing that print_r/var_dump would.

Comment: How would that help? `print_r` shows that field just fine.

Comment: this is possibly a page encoding issue?  tried everything as utf-8?

Comment: Are you 100000% percent sure you get the expected result when trying to upload that exact same file on your 'old' server using the exact same code? Also does it also happen with other files?

Comment: @AndyD273: do you have `magic_quotes` enabled as stated in the bugticket cosmoba points out?

Comment: @PeeHaa, Yeah. The site has had magic_quotes_gpc enabled since before I inherited it. I know it helps security a bit, since it escapes some of the stuff that an injection attack might cause, but otherwise I don't know any pros/cons to it.

Comment: @AndyD273: and about preventing sql injection: we have functions for that :) (mysql_real_escape_string, prepared statements etc :) )

Comment: @PeeHaa, Thanks for the security lesson. As it stands, I'm currently the only developer that's using this server. I can see the benefits to removing the dependence on it, however it may be a bit of a long term project. I've been going through cleaning up stuff in the site, fixing stuff from before, and as I improve my own knowledge. If I were to just shut it off, I can see bad things happening, so it'll probably be a long term thing.

Comment: @AndyD273: You are right when you say you cannot shut it off anymore now (without going back through all your code to implement sql injection prevention). That's also one of the reasons it sucks :) Anyway as long as you keep on learning you should be fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the bug you are experiencing [$_FILES 'name' missing first character after upload.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55510)

I am having the same issue.

Comment: Well if it is related to `magic_quotes` being enabled. Serves you right! ;)

Comment: I do have magic quotes enable. And it is enabled on the old server. 
PeeHaa, if I may ask, what's wrong with magic quotes? I'm curious, if it's something that I should try to weed out. It's been this way on this site since I inherited it, and I never cared enough to want to try to get rid of it. @cosmoba, so is the solution to this to install the beta version of php?

Comment: @AndyD273: magic_quotes can be used to prevent sql injection although it is consider bad (well I do, and I'm sure many will agree) for multiple reasons. What will happen when depending on magic_quotes for a project and some1 else installs the project with magic quotes disabled? magic_quotes also does it's job on variables not even being used for database transactions (performance). If some1 else uses the server for a project it will screw up his expected var values. etc. Basically it is 'security' (within quotes) for people who don't know how to properly write secure code.

Comment: @AndyD273: if it is a production server I wouldn't use beta version. I think you have two options: 1. Use 5.3.6 2. wait for 5.3.9 . According to the ticket it has been fixed in SVN @ 2011-08-29 21:12 UTC

Comment: I wonder how long it'll be until 5.3.9 comes out... 5.3.6 may be my only option at the moment, as we're hoping to do the switch in the next week or so.

Comment: @AndyD273: If that's the case you should go for 5.3.6 for sure

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and search a lot but it's a bug and I don't know why! But I have solution and it works as well.
Just prefix a name before file name. Example :

```
'fileNamePrefix_' . $_FILES['file_name_attribute']['name']
```

Comment: Are you still using PHP 5.3? I've been really enjoying PHP 7 for a little while now, so if you have the ability to upgrade you might want to look into it. It's got some neat new features, and a lot of security fixes since 5.3...

Comment: Yes I know but i don't familiar with PHP 7 because I'm a little busy. Thank you for you rate.